# dlinfo and dladdr1 missing from Android

Tags: android, elf

I am trying to use `dlinfo` to access the dynamic section of the shared object (using the link_map structure) but it seems that `dlinfo` is not included in Android?

References

https://groups.google.com/g/android-ndk/c/iMamH_6dkj0

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36907396

Then I saw that `dladdr1` also allows the retrieval of the link_map structure but it seems that `dladdr1` is also not included in Android?

What are the alternatives if I want to retrieve the link_map structure and eventually retrieve details about the dynamic secion of a shared object (including main executable) in Android?